# my magento store displays empty shopping cart after adding product to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I did go through all solution. I did changes cookies from admin but still it displays the same empty cart errro . Please give me some other solution to fix this problem . I am using magento latest version 1.9.2

Comment: you need to make sure you have no errors in logs, your cookie is not reset, and cookie domain name and path is correct. also you need form_key

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a multiwebsite with different domains and Frontend uses https. When customers go to checkout/cart page, they will be redirected from this domain to another domain. Therefore, it causes the empty cart